# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'comment_status = 'Approved' ORDER BY comment_id DESC' at line 1

This is my code

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = {$the_post_id}";
    $query .= "AND comment_status = 'Approved' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY comment_id DESC";
    $select_comment_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$select_comment_query){
        die('Query Failed'. mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_comment_query)) {
        $comment_date = $row['comment_date'];
        $comment_content = $row['comment_content'];
        $comment_author = $row['comment_author'];
?>

<!-- Comments -->
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $comment_author; ?>
            <small><?php echo $comment_date; ?></small>
        </h4>
        <?php echo $comment_content; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

If I disable the following codes, it works

```
    $query .= "AND comment_status = 'Approved' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY comment_id DESC";
```

Thank you

Comment: I thin one more space required after `{$the_post_id}` or before `AND` in second line.

Comment: Right before you call `mysqli_query()`, `echo` the contents of `$query` to see if you're passing the query you think you're passing.

Comment: its not good to mark first to someone and then mark another one.

Comment: And i think my answer is more descriptive and more good suggestion is there. No offense, i deleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including a space:

```
$query .= " AND comment_status = 'Approved' ";
```

As a note:  if you want to debug these types of problems, then output the query string before running it.  Often the problem is obvious.